# How to integrate social media for photo sharing on iOS?

Tags: iphone, social-networking, photolibrary

I need to integrate social media for sharing a photo in my app. My app will have one UIImageView with some image and one button for sharing the image. As soon as I click on the button I should get the list of social networking apps installed on my iPhone and I should be able to share the image on selecting any one of them as shown in the figure below.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try ShareKit (https://github.com/ShareKit)